# Passing function pointer from member function

Tags: c++

I was trying out a code snippet and came across the following error on VS2010.

```
Error   1   error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression    Line 19
```

Following is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class a
{
public:
    void add(int x)
    {
        cout<<x+x<<endl;
    }
    void mult(int x)
    {
        cout<<x*x<<endl;
    }
    typedef void (a::*fptr)(int);
    fptr retFuncP(char ch)
    {
        if(ch=='+')
        {
            return &add;
        }
        else
        {
            return &mult;
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    a objA;
    void (a::*fptr)(int) = objA.retFuncP('+');
    (objA.*fptr)(3);
    cin.ignore();
}
```

Use of `void (a::*retFuncP(char ch))(int x)` as an alternative didn't solve the problem as well. What seems to be wrong in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `&a::add` instead of `&add`, because `add` is a member function. Same with `&mult` which needs to be `&a::mult`.  See [demo](http://ideone.com/kT98vp) with these fixes.